# Golang how to convert type integer to type byte

Tags: go

How can I convert an integer `3` to byte `'3'`?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {   
    num := 3
    b := byte(num)

    if b == '3' { fmt.Println("how to make this line true") }

    fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", b, b) // 3, uint8
    fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", '3', '3') // 51, int32
}
```

Comment: `int32` is not a byte, it's four bytes. `uint8` is a byte. Also the byte `'3'` will never equal the byte `3` because the character `3` is not at the code point `0x03`.

Comment: what is the correct way to convert number 3 to a four-byte 3?

Comment: What do you mean by "a four-byte 3"? `int32(3)` is a four-byte integer representing the number 3. `'3'` is the four-byte representation of the utf-8 code point for the character `3`. It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you say you want to do, you could do this:

```
strconv.Itoa(3)[0] == '3'
```

https://play.golang.com/p/LFDDf1JfWDQ

However, as pointed out by others, this is probably not what you *actually* want to do.